# WPF Prevent memory leaks when our ViewModel is a static object

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, memory-leaks

I now there is something in `WPF` coding that maybe cause `Memory leaks`. like removing objects contain eventhandlers that subscribed in a *long life* resources. In this regard, I have read [this article](http://svetoslavsavov.blogspot.com/2010/05/memory-leaks-in-wpf-applications.html).

Now, my question is:

If our resource was a `ViewModel` and we keep it in a `Static` object and give it to a `Window` `DataContext` or `DataContext` of a `UserControl` inside the `Window`, when we want to `Close` our `Window` should we do *all* of the following works to prevent `Memory leaks`? :

- Unsubscribe *all* `EventHandlers` of the `Window` or `UserControl` from the `ViewModel` events manualy
- Unbind *all* bound `Elements Properties` to the `ViewModel` manualy
- Unbind *all* bound `Commands` to the `ViewModel` manualy

If answer is Yes, what is your suggestion way to do these works automatically in one or several methods, then call them on `Window Closing`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Unsubscribe all EventHandlers of the Window or UserControl from the ViewModel events manualy

Yes. If the window subscribes to a VM event, then the VM will hold a reference to the subscriber. Note that this is not unique to WPF, any static object will hold event references like this.  If you do not want to manually unsubscribe then you can use the [Weak Event Pattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/aa970850(v=vs.100).aspx). Generally I find it simpler to just unsubscribe.

- Unbind all bound Elements Properties to the ViewModel manualy
- Unbind all bound Commands to the ViewModel manualy

No, generally you do not need to worry about bindings. The only cases are where the bound object is not a DependencyProperty or something that implements INotifyPropertyChanged. Since in MVVM you are generally binding to VM properties, and the VM implements INPC you are fine.

For this reason it is good practice to ALWAYS implement INPC in your VMs, even if you never fire it. I have had leaks in the past where I've not bothered with INPC because the VM properties never change after construction.

The only other ones to watch are the examples given in the article, such as Count. However, these have rarely caused problems for me. If you do find yourself with memory leaks, then you can use the tools outlined in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2259443/660536) to find the culprits.